# jquery-ui menu collapse first category onload

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, jquery-ui

i'm trying to use jquery-ui menu which is pretty good but I face some issues like:

1. First category is always opened onload.
2. When a category is chosen and the page is refresh the current category is closed and the first category is opened.

I'm using the default configuration.

My code is pretty simple:

```
 <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
  </script>

    <div id="accordion">
          <h3>Teste categ1</h3>
          <div>

                <a href="<?php echo base_url().'categorie/1/1';?>">Tip1</a>
                <a href="">teste c1 subc1</a>
                <a href="">teste c1 subc2</a>
                <a href="">teste c1 subc3</a>

          </div>

        <h3>Teste categ2</h3>
            <div>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url().'categorie/2/1';?>">Tip1</a>
                    <a href="">teste c2 subc1</a>
                    <a href="">teste c2 subc2</a>
                    <a href="">teste c2 subc3</a>

            </div>
    </div>
```

If somehow is possible to open second category onload then is chosen it will be great.
Thanks!

Comment: You can add some hash in url and then can check for it and open the appropriate accordion.

Answer (score 1):

By default jQuery accordion makes first tab active.If you want different tab active  you need to tell it.Suppose if you want to make 2nd tab active you need to write this way

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
    active: 2      
});
```

You can see more details [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)